# Admin bar and fixed header issue?

Tags: headers, admin-bar

I've styled my header to have a fixed top position. While logged in to wordpress, the wp admin nav bar covers the top section of my header making imposible to access my top navigation. I would like for the wp admin nav to push my top navigation below so both are visible. Does anyone know of any solution to fix this problem?

An example of my problem can be found at...
[www.nickriversdesign.com/dev](http://www.nickriversdesign.com/dev)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in your css you could try something like: `body.logged-in{margin-top:20px;}` or if this doesnt work some other code using the `.logged-in` class

Comment: This (incorrectly) affects all logged in users. Consider the answer by Brent instead.

Answer (score 29):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
body.admin-bar #branding-wrap{top: 28px;} 
body.admin-bar #wrapper{margin-top: 145px;}
```

the `body.admin-bar`declaration at the front will make sure that these styles only get applied when the admin bar is visible.

Comment: body.admin-bar is the correct selector (and this the correct answer). Zach L's answer affects all logged in users, but only logged in users with content editing permissions have the admin bar visible and need the header moved down the page.

Comment: interesting... I've never personally had a setup with any users without these permissions.  I imagine its the same as if in the user settings they disable the admin bar.

Comment: Version note: `.admin-bar` is not longer appearing in WordPress 4. It's now called `#wpadminbar` and does not wrap the content, therefore the above cannot be applied to version 4+

Comment: A SASS version is also available, together with explanation for mobiles/desktop resolutions (responsive websites) and mobile-first approach: https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-sticky-headers-wordpress-admin-bar-behave/

Comment: How will this work once the user is scrolling down? Then the wp navigation bar will be stuck "almost at top of screen" which looks rather stupid

Answer (score 2):

Try this for WordPress 4+. It checks if the admin bar is present and if so move the fixed header down a bit to compensate.

```
    //fix for admin bar
    if ($('#wpadminbar')[0])
        $('.site-header').css('top', '32px')
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Changing '.site-header' to 'body' got this to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works as well

```css
body.logged-in > header {  
    margin-top: 32px;  
}
```

Comment: Please try to add a bit of an explanation - this will allow the OP and future users to learn and understand what's happening rather than just being a place where people get their code written for them.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: The parent selector is not needed. `body.logged-in header` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, on devices with smaller widths, wpadminbar is not positioned fixed. So if you scroll the document in a smartphone, the admin bar will follow the scroll and will not stay at the top of the window. With keeping this in mind, why not add some javascript in the footer of your theme just after the `wp_head()` call. This way we can target the device width and whether or not the document has the adminbar. Then simply make some CSS rules and append it to the document head - like below!

```
<script>
( function(e) {
    var ab = document.getElementById( 'wpadminbar' );
    if ( typeof( ab ) === 'object' && window.innerWidth >= 610 ) {
        var abh = ab.offsetHeight || ab.clientHeight || ab.scrollHeight;
        var style = document.createElement( 'style' );
        style.id = 'adminbar_main_nav_controle_rules';
        document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( style );
        var rules = document.createTextNode( 'body.admin-bar .main-navigation.fixed { margin-top: ' + abh + 'px !important; }' );
        style.appendChild( rules );
        console.debug( 'wpadmibar space is covered' );
    }
})();
</script>
```

Assuming your nav has a class `'main-navigation'` and on scroll you add another class named `'fixed'` to it. Change the CSS to target your navigation panel by replacing `'body.admin-bar .main-navigation.fixed'` with howsoever you would want to target yours.

It can be further improved for example checking if the admin bar is fixed or not, but for now, I hope it will helps.

Answer (score 1):

I read all answers but didn't find that one:

Why not use wp function:

```
is_admin_bar_showing()
```

example header.php theme file

```
<nav class="nav-default" style="<?php echo is_admin_bar_showing() ? 'top: 32px' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: I was looking a while for adjusting the WordPress admin bar with the fixed-top navbar in Bootstrap 5. That was the best solution that worked like a charm for me without adding too much extra code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just used this CSS.

```
body.admin-bar #main-header  {
padding-top: 32px }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it is works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#wpadminbar')[0]) {
        $('header').css('top', '32px')
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

give the top navbar

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative!
}
```